# How to store and retrieve tiles to/from the database using php?

Tags: php, arrays, grid, 2d, tile

```
<?php 
    $val = 0;
    $twoD = array( 
        array("0,0,0,1,0,0"),
        array("0,0,0,1,1,0"),
        array("0,0,0,1,0,0"),
        array("0,0,0,1,1,0"),
        array("0,0,0,1,0,1")); 

    for($r = 0; $r <  count($twoD) ; $r++)
    {
        for($c = 0; $c < count($twoD); $c++) 
            echo $twoD[$r][$c];
            echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

(Pure PHP) to start, 
I'm actually trying to make a 2d tile-based map - and I really don't have any idea how.. I already have the images for that. In the array there are 0's and 1's.. 0's will be the tiles that the character can't walk through could be a grass image or stone image. So, how can I store these 0's and 1's to the database having the image content I wish to assign. Please guide me with this. (*sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0):

You can use json format to solve this. You can use json_encode() for storing in database and json_decode for converting to php array again from database.

Hope this helps